# I can't understand {{{ body }}} in Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

It's translated, I'm not fluent in English yet, maybe it's not exact in some parts, well my question is, why the
`{{{ body }}}` 
in an hbs file (example: 'main.hbs') and how? I know what is going to include me in this file ('main.hbs')?

I leave you the 'main.hbs' example...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{{ body }}} <!-- Aquí -->
</body>
</html>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias a quien responda a esta duda...

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Pablo, a ver si te ayuda el ejemplo!

Answer (score 1):

The `{{{ body }}}` block is replaced by handlebars by the contents of the rendered template, for instance this route wants to render the `index.hbs` template:

```js
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.render("index", { title: "Homepage" });
});
```

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/express-handlebars-example-2zpw44?file=/index.js:11,46).
And the template itself is:

```
<main>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage</p>
</main>
```

The whole HTML output will look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage</p>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Three pair of curlies (`{{{ ... }}}`) instead of two are needed to prevent HTML escaping.